# Проблема с delphi

Tags: delphi

Я с инета скачал себе delphi. Установил, запускаю. Там что-то для создания модулей. Нажимаю New-->Application. Всё равно таже фигня. Что делать? Может быть скачать какой-нибудь другой?! Всмысле там открывается файл Unit1.pas для редактирования.

Comment: Мы кочнено все всё поняли про "ту фигню" и сейчас что нибудь посоветуем.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы создать модуль нужно нажать File->New->Unit или File->New->Other, и в открывшемся окне выбрать Unit. А что за версия Delphi? Что-то я не совсем понял: приложение не получается создать или модуль? У меня всегда получалось создавать и то, и другое. Если поугадывать из-за чего у Вас эта проблема, то тут возможно несколько вариантов: может поставилась криво (полностью снесите и переставьте), может левая версия попалась (качайте другую), может Вашей Винде она чем-то не понравилась или не понравилась анитивирусу (если версия 5-7).

Comment: Не получается создать приложение! Коньсольное ещё получается, а оконное не как!

Comment: Попробуйте переставить - может поставилась криво, не прокатит -  качайте другую версию. Скорее всего, проблема была во время установки или версия сама по себе кривая. У меня такой проблемы не было.

Comment: Скорее всего сама по себе кривая так как я уже переустанавливал.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже ставил DELPHI из дистрибутива,
скачанного из сети(надо внимательно выбирать-откуда).
Чел, который советовал, откуда качать,
писал, что на W7 будет постоянно сообщать,
что есть проблемы совместимости, можно на них не
обращать вним.
У меня File-New-Application и появляется
форма для разработки.